# Where best to place the Java Libaries for common usage? (Best practice ?)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse / Java dev

We consume lots of libraries like Log4J, JDom, Apache Configuration etc in all our applications

Right now I create a lib folder in Eclipse projects and add these libraries to all projects and then create JAR which includes these libraries too

I don't want to copy the same libraries again and again and also bundle them as these are common to all my applications. I obviously want to reduce the foot print of my applcations

Are there any best practices?

Thanks

Comment: Use a dependency management system? Like Maven

Comment: Use Maven, Ivy, or some other dependency manager.

Comment: I suggest Maven, it's the most used one I think.

Comment: I'll add Gradle to the list although I've mostly seen Maven especially for J2SE and J2EE

Comment: Maven is fine but that's additional tool to maintain. We only build simple Java executable (JAR) using Eclipse and not complex applications

Comment: Maven is much easier as what you are doing right now. Just install the m2e plugin for Eclipse (some Eclipse versions already have it), create a pom.xml, convert your project (just a click in Eclipse) and you are done. Adding a new library becomes adding an XML tag to file. Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Maven or Gradle are going to be the common/obvious recommendations, but those tools have a steep learning curve and are not, IMO, the right choice for *every* project (many, but not all).

For manually managing these dependencies, having individual copies in each project is better than trying to share them across projects/applications. The reason is that sharing libraries couples every project/application to the same versions of those libraries; what happens when you want to migrate one of those applications to use a newer version of one of the libraries? All the other applications would also get that new version (which may or may not be desirable, and can lead to some "head-scratcher" problems).

You're not going to be able to reduce the "footprint" of the applications, because in the end, no matter how you manage them, each application has to have access to the libraries it needs.

Dependency management tools like Maven and Gradle actually take this approach, it's just that they hide the work of copying of JARs around.

Answer (score 1):

First thing i will suggest is started using `maven` it handles the dependency problem very well

or

Just you can define a `"User Library"` like `windows -> preferences -> java ->User Libraries ->new` and then select the library created and add jars add all the jars in it.

Next time just add that user library to the desired project instead of all the jars.